# AWS lambda and dynamodb pagination

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Suppose I have a dynamodb table with about 1500 records and primary id called "PK". These 1500 records has a field called Name which indicate to whom the record belong to. When a user go to my website, I call api gateway and calling the lambda to retrieve all the records belong to him - for this I must use scan because the primary id is not known, only the user name.

I want my website to support pagination, that is, instead of scanning all the 1500 records and find only the ones relevant for the requested user name I want to only get the first 50 and then continue to request more.

How can I achieve this? I can't see a way to avoid using scan on the dynamodb table because I don't have a primary key to look for and the only way I can think of to achieve better performance is to scan less items and return them back as fast as I can to the website.

Comment: check this link may be userful for you :: https://www.talentica.com/blogs/dynamo-db-pagination/

Comment: Are you sure you want to do scan with pagination instead of having another global secondary index?